# How to set the thread stack size during compile time?

Tags: rust

When attempting to run a program that builds a large [`clap::App`](http://kbknapp.github.io/clap-rs/clap/struct.App.html#) ([find the source here](https://github.com/Byron/google-apis-rs/blob/clap/gen/dfareporting2d1-cli/src/main.rs)), I get a stackoverflow: `thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack`.

So far I was unable to figure out how to instruct `rustc` to increase the stacksize for a brute-force workaround. `RUST_MIN_STACK` seems to apply only to runtime, and even there it didn't seem to have any effect.

As the code is generated, what I would probably have to do is to move the `SubCommand` creation to the runtime, which is what I will try next.

**However, do you see a way to fix this differently ?**

*It seems quite important to figure this one out as the builder patterns appears to be prone to this issue, if the built structure is just large and nested enough.*

## How to reproduce

```
git clone -b clap https://github.com/Byron/google-apis-rs
cd google-apis-rs
git checkout 9a8ae4b
make dfareporting2d1-cli-cargo ARGS=run
```

Please note that you will need my fork of [quasi](https://github.com/Byron/rust-quasi) and set an override locally to allow building with the latest compiler.

## Meta

```
➜  google-apis-rs git:(clap) rustc --version
rustc 1.1.0-nightly (97d4e76c2 2015-04-27) (built 2015-04-28)
```

Comment: I guess it is operating system specific.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no way to set the stack size of the main thread in Rust. In fact, an assumption about the size of the main thread's stack is made at the source code level in the Rust runtime library (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/rt/mod.rs#L85).

The environment variable `RUST_MIN_STACK` influences the stack size of threads created within the program that's not the main thread, but you could just as easily specify that value within your source code at runtime.

The most straightforward way to solve your problem might be to run the clap in a separate thread you create, so that you can control its stack size.

Take this code for example:

```
extern crate clap;
use clap::App;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let child = thread::Builder::new().stack_size(32 * 1024 * 1024).spawn(move || {
        return App::new("example")
            .version("v1.0-beta")
            .args_from_usage("<INPUT> 'Sets the input file to use'")
            .get_matches();
    }).unwrap();

    let matches = child.join().unwrap();

    println!("INPUT is: {}", matches.value_of("INPUT").unwrap());
}
```

clap appears to be able to terminate the application correctly from within the child thread so your code should work with little modification.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out ! I would still love to be able to set this value for the main-thread at compile time - maybe one day this is supported by rustc.

Comment: The link to /src/libstd/rt/mod.rs#L85 is invalid now.

New relevant link: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d5c2e9c342b358556da91d61ed4133f6f50fc0c3/src/doc/man/rustc.1#L282