# How to increase the stack size available to a Rust library?

Tags: stack, rust, os-agnostic

I am playing with lambda calculus and would like to have a bit more stack space to be able to build and compute (very) long function chains. Is there a way to increase it for the crate, similar to increasing the recursion limit (`#![recursion_limit = "100"]`)?

The crate is a library and I would like it to be able to perform stack-intensive operations regardless of the target operating system.

Comment: Do you want to increase the stack size of the stack the compiler operates on **or** the [stack of *your* program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937697/how-to-set-the-thread-stack-size-during-compile-time)?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt the issue occurred during cargo tests and the overflowed thread was `libname-hash.exe`, so I guess it's the program after all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research I concluded that there isn't a universal way to achieve what I am after, but using `std::thread::Builder` I was able to create an extra thread with a specified stack size and perform stack-heavy operations inside it:

```
fn huge_reduction() {
    let builder = thread::Builder::new()
                  .name("reductor".into())
                  .stack_size(32 * 1024 * 1024); // 32MB of stack space

    let handler = builder.spawn(|| {
        // stack-intensive operations
    }).unwrap();

    handler.join().unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a language feature, it's an operating system feature. On *nix systems, you will use a tool like `ulimit`. Other systems likely use other tools:

- [How to change the stack size using ulimit or per process on Mac OS X for a C or Ruby program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245019/how-to-change-the-stack-size-using-ulimit-or-per-process-on-mac-os-x-for-a-c-or)
- [How to increase stack size permanently on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/340239/130901)

Comment: @ljedrz: I'll note that [`std::thread::Builder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/std/thread/struct.Builder.html) let you specify the stack size of the created thread from within the program. Only the stack size of the *main* thread is set by the OS.

Comment: @MatthieuM. can you really set a stack size of like 256MB that way? Also, linking to the Rust 1.8 documentation? It's much better to link to [the current docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html), which clarifies what *unit* `stack_size` takes.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I blame Google for the link ;) As for the maximum stack size, it may indeed be limited by the OS, or by the underlying thread implementation, but you *can* tune it from within Rust.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I was under the impression that `ulimit` (and other OS equivalents) was what controlled the maximum; do you know if that's true?

Comment: @Shepmaster: No idea, the only times I've hit a stackoverflow was because of an unbounded recursion, so the fix was in the logic, not in the OS. I don't use FreeBSD though, which is notorious for its small stacks (1MB or 2MB by default I think).