# How to deserialize a nested big array

Tags: rust

I have a type `Foo` which contains a big array. With the help of `serde_big_array`, `serde_derive`, and `serde_with`, I can derive serialization and deserializalization.

```rust
use serde_big_array;
use serde_big_array::BigArray;
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};

pub const SIZE: usize = 30000;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(with = "BigArray")]
    pub vals: [bool; SIZE],
}
```

This works fine.

However, when use this type in another structure I run into trouble.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Bar {
    field0: Foo,
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn deserialization_attempt_test() {
        let foo = Foo {
            vals: [false; SIZE],
        };
        let instance: Bar = Bar { field0: foo };
        let json = serde_json::to_string(&instance).unwrap();
        println!("PMD0");
        let s_back = serde_json::from_str::<Bar>(&json).unwrap();
        println!("PMD1");
    }
}
```

Running this tests with `cargo t deserialization_attempt_test -- --nocapture` prints `PMD0` but not `PMD1`. The test fails with the message

```
thread 'tests::deserialization_attempt' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
```

How do I implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize` for `Bar`?

Comment: I found the `serde_stacker` crate and followed the description in their README. https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-stacker

But I don't know how to get that code to work through the `serialize`/`deserialize` methods.

Comment: Changing the type of `vals` from `[bool; 30_000]` to `Vec<bool>` of same size makes the deserialization work. So that's an option if you can live with reduced type safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your JSON deserializer in a `serde_stacker` instance, then it works without setting the environment variable that @munksgaard suggests.

```rust
    #[test]
    fn serialization_bug_fix_attempt_test() {
        let foo = Foo {
            vals: [false; SIZE],
        };

        let instance: Bar = Bar { field0: foo };
        let json = serde_json::to_string(&instance).unwrap();
        println!("PMD0");
        let mut deserializer: serde_json::Deserializer<serde_json::de::StrRead> =
            serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(&json);
        let deserializer = serde_stacker::Deserializer::new(&mut deserializer);
        let value: Value = Value::deserialize(deserializer).unwrap();
        let target: Bar = from_value(value).unwrap();
        println!("PMD1");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the stack (when running through `cargo test`) is too small to handle your test. Note that if you move `deserialization_attempt_test` into a main function and run it with `cargo run` it will work. Similarly if you reduce the array size to e.g. 2000 it will also work.

A workaround, although not that satsifying, is to manually set `RUST_MIN_STACK` when running `cargo test`. For instance, this will work:

```
RUST_MIN_STACK=8388608 cargo test
```

More information about the error can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937697/how-to-set-the-thread-stack-size-during-compile-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955243/cargo-test-release-causes-a-stack-overflow-why-doesnt-cargo-bench). [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/#stack-size) is the documentation on `RUST_MIN_STACK`.