# How do I use `serde_stacker` in my `deserialize` implementation?

Tags: json, rust, serde

[I have a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72618777/how-to-deserialize-a-nested-big-array) that I can only deserialize if I use the `serde_stacker`. So in order to deserialize the struct `Bar` I need to first convert it to a `serde_json::value::Value` type that is used to hold JSON values, and then convert it to the desired `Bar` type.

```rust
const SIZE: usize = 30000;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(with = "BigArray")]
    vals: [bool; SIZE],
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Bar {
    field0: Foo,
}

impl Bar {
    fn custom_deserialization_test(instance: Bar) {
        let json = serde_json::to_string(&instance).unwrap();
        let mut deserializer: serde_json::Deserializer<serde_json::de::StrRead> =
            serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(&json);
        let deserializer: serde_stacker::Deserializer<
            &mut serde_json::Deserializer<serde_json::de::StrRead>,
        > = serde_stacker::Deserializer::new(&mut deserializer);
        let value: Value = Value::deserialize(deserializer).unwrap();
        let target: Bar = from_value(value).unwrap();
    }
}
```

My question is: How do I overwrite `Bar`'s `deserialize` method to use the `serde_stacker` deserializer instead of the regular `serde_json` deserializer as I do above?

I might need some kind of wrapper but the `from_value` function call on the last line of code uses the derived `deserialize` method of `Bar` to convert from the JSON object to type `Bar`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input JSON to deserialize? EDIT: May not be necessary as I can create my own as you demonstrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bar::deserialize` function is generic over the `Deserializer` used. This means you can use `serde_stacker::Deserializer` instead of a `Deserializer` from `serde_json`. Your posted code snippet already shows how to use `serde_stacker` on the `Value` type. You only need to replace it with `Bar`.

```rust
impl Bar {
    fn custom_deserialization_test(instance: Bar) {
        let json = serde_json::to_string(&instance).unwrap();
        let mut deserializer: serde_json::Deserializer<serde_json::de::StrRead> =
            serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(&json);
        let deserializer: serde_stacker::Deserializer<
            &mut serde_json::Deserializer<serde_json::de::StrRead>,
        > = serde_stacker::Deserializer::new(&mut deserializer);
        let target = Bar::deserialize(deserializer).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to achieve this with fewer lines, or wrapping it in an `impl`?

Comment: Using fewer lines is not really possible. You always need to 1) create JSON deserializer, 2) wrap it in the `serde_stacker` deserializer, 3) call `Bar::deserialize`. You can remove the type annotations for the local variables, saving some lines by inferring the types. The code is already in an `impl`, so that works too.